# XSLT Dynamic Columns in XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, key, grouping

I have an example xml, below,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
<Row>
<Group>Group A</Group>
<Date>2013-09-02</Date>
<Value>200</Value>
</Row>
<Row>
<Group>Group A</Group>
<Date>2013-09-02</Date>
<Value>500</Value>
</Row>
<Row>
<Group>Group A</Group>
<Date>2013-10-02</Date>
<Value>400</Value>
</Row>
<Row>
<Group>Group B</Group>
<Date>2013-09-02</Date>
<Value>250</Value>
</Row>
</Root>
```

I have an xslt (version 1.0) that would be used to summarise the data, with dynamic columns. I have the code create the HTML table and the results show the correct number of columns and the correct number of rows, I cannot get the cells in the main body of the table to sum the values in the "Value" node of the XML above.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:lookup="http://any.com/lookup" exclude-result-prefixes="lookup">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:decimal-format name="NN" NaN="-" />
    <lookup:Dates>
        <Date value="2013-09-02" />
        <Date value="2013-10-02" />
        <Date value="2013-11-04" />
        <Date value="2013-12-02" />
        <Date value="2014-01-02" />
        <Date value="2014-02-03" />
        <Date value="2014-03-03" />
    </lookup:Dates>
    <xsl:key name="Dates" match="/xsl:stylesheet/lookup:Dates" use="Date" />
    <xsl:key name="Group" match="Row" use="Group" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
<style type="text/css">
table {border:1px solid #000;border-collapse:collapse}
td {border:1px solid #000;border-collapse:collapse}
</style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Group</td>
                        <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/lookup:Dates/Date">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/Root/Row[count(. | key('Group', Group)[1])=1]">
                        <xsl:sort select="Group" data-type="text" order="ascending" />
                        <xsl:variable name="curGroup" select="key('Group', Group)" />
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$curGroup/Group" />
                            </td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/lookup:Dates/Date">
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="sum($curGroup[/Root/Row/Date=current()/Dates/Date]/Value)" />
                                </td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting HTML is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
table {border:1px solid #000;border-collapse:collapse}
td {border:1px solid #000;border-collapse:collapse}
</style>
</head>
<body><table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>Group</td>
<td>2013-09-02</td>
<td>2013-10-02</td>
<td>2013-11-04</td>
<td>2013-12-02</td>
<td>2014-01-02</td>
<td>2014-02-03</td>
<td>2014-03-03</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Group A</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Group B</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
</table></body>
</html>
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong? I assume it is in the xpath in the line

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum($curGroup[/Root/Row/Date=current()/Dates/Date]/Value)" />
```

Many thanks

Graham

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. You say "dynamic columns", yet your column names are hard-coded into the stylesheet. A dynamic solution would be purely data-driven.

Comment: Solved!

The xpath was incorrect in the sum statement, corrected to:

    <xsl:value-of select="sum($curGroup[Date=current()/@value]/Value)" />

now gives me the correct summary for the groups and the totals

Comment: The dates in the lookup:Dates node would be updated dynamically when the xsl is loaded before the xml is transformed

Comment: Now struggling with the final totals row:

`code`
<tr>
      <td>Totals</td>
      <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/lookup:Dates/Date">
       <td class="right">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(Root/Row[Date=current()/@value]/Value)" />
       </td>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </tr>`code`

Just shows zeros in the final total row for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a grand total row, then doing this won't work...

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/lookup:Dates/Date"> 
   <td class="right"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(Root/Row[Date=current()/@value]/Value)" /> 
   </td> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

This is because inside the **xsl:for-each** loop your context is the **Date** element, so doing the xpath expression of **Root/Row** will be relative to that.

The solution is simply to define a variable (before the loop) holding all **Row** elements, and then reference that. Try this:

```
<xsl:variable name="allGroups" select="//Row" />
<xsl:for-each select="//Dates/Date">
    <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="sum($allGroups[Date=current()/@value]/Value)" />
    </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```